# Is it possible to transform an HTML button into a input text field with transition effect ? if possible how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;  border-radius: 2px;  background-color: #f4511e;  border: none;  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 14px;   font-family:'Lato',arial;  color:white;   padding:5px; 
    transition: all 0.5s;  cursor: pointer;   height:30px;  width:90px;     
  }



.search {
margin-bottom:-20px; border-top-left-radius:6px;  border-top-right-radius:2px;  border-bottom-right-radius:2px;  
border-bottom-left-radius:6px;  border:1px solid #b3daff; height:25px; outline: none; margin-right:-3px;
  }
```

```html
<button class="button" id="green">lookafter</button>

<input type="text" class="search" id="box" style="width: 100px; display: none;"  placeholder="lookafter"  autofocus />
```

```
 I need the button to transform  into input field  by animation of 1 second. and change back to button when any other button is clicked
```

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37603790/edit) to make it easier to read and understand. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

wrap both the button and the input in a div.
give both the input and the button the same height and width, additionally give them position absolute, with top: 0 and left: 0.

now you can toggle between them by toggling opacity between 1 and 0. you need to set display none on the faded element just after the opacity becomes 0, not before.

Comment: Give a more thorough explanation and show some actual code.